# Java Android - setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

When using the following code i keep getting errors, 
i know there is another way of using the onclick functions, android:onclick... 
but i prefer this 'cleaner' way.

the id name of the textview is right but i keep getting this error with the onclicklistener.

what am i doing wrong?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(usernameText);
    text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // Do some job here

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_screen, menu);
    return true;
}`
```

Comment: what's error are you getting?

Comment: make sure you have this import statement import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

Comment: also, define 'cleaner' ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem may be a jar that you imported that has an onClickListener...

Try add this:

```
text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // Do some job here

    }
});
```

Comment: @Raghunandan, the OP's code doesn't specify View.OnClickListener.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel i think the problem is with the wrong import statement

Comment: @Raghunandan, I agree... but it would import the right class if you specify View (I believe).

Comment: Probably... But if he uses dialog onClickListenner as well, even if he imports the package View, he will have the same problem...

Comment: this code works for me, but i haven't added any jar's. and adding import view.onclicklistener didn't work.

Comment: When you do a View.onClickListener the package is automatically imported if you use eclipe

Answer (score 3):

without seeing your error, I'd guess that you probably imported the wrong OnClickListener. Make sure that it's the View one.

Comment: also, if you want my 2 cents, this approach is by no means "cleaner" than just setting onClick in the XML.

Comment: i checked if it was the view one but this didn't do anything about my error.

Comment: well, you selected the exact same answer as mine as the "right" answer, so, it must have been the issue! :)

Answer (score 0):

May be you should take your screenshot and upload here, but please looking for your code:

Ensure you

```
import View.OnClickListener
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(usernameText);
text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // Do some job here

    }
});
```

Comment: Don't you want to tell us something about your code?