# How can I set onClickListeners on TextViews

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development I am just wondering that like we have onclicklisteners on buttons can we have a onclicklisteners on textviews also? I tried this but it does not work

```
TextView numbers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numbers_textview);
numbers.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // my logic
    }
});
```

The error I got is:

> cannot resolve symbol 'setOnClickListener'

If someone can help it will be really helpful for me thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks ok - verify and add your imports to post : `import android.widget.TextView` and `import android.view.View.OnClickListener` .  Or `androidx` equivalents.  (The `setOnClickListener` comes from the `View` parent class which is common to both Button and TextView - actually Button is a subclass of TextView!)

Comment: `Invalidate and restart` is always an option if this really seems like something which should work (which it does).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Android - setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708684/java-android-setonclicklistenerview-onclicklistener-in-the-type-view-is-not)